# Html <A> link with variable

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
 <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?>

    <li><?php echo $row["msg"] ;?>(id: <?php echo $row["msg_id"] ;?>) | sent at <?php echo $row["data"] ;?> <a href="message.php">see</a> | <a href="delete.php?msg_id=<?php $row["msg_id"]?>">delete</a></li>

 <?php 

    }
 ?>
```

but  it doesn't work. The msg_id is correctly and the db informations are good, but i don't know how to make the url like `delete.php?msg_id= $ROW_MSG_ID`.
Maybe you could help me. Thanks!

Comment: You're just missing `echo` before `$row["msg_id"]` in the `<a>`. You did it right all the other times on the line.

Comment: @Barmar oh, thank you bro. I wasn't careful. Thanks alot

Comment: You can try the shorthand for `<?php echo $a; ?>` with `<?= $a; ?>`just a little advice

Comment: Just be wary that deletes over a http get can be dangerous.  Browsers can pre-fetch and send your items to the bit-bucket!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
/* This code is a little bit hard to read.  
It would be much easier to troubleshoot if it is cleaner.  
Besides that, the problem could be your message.php or delete.php.  
This code is actually fine by itself. */?>


<li>
    <?php
        echo $row['msg'].'(id: '.$row['msg_id'].') | sent at '.$row['data'];
        echo '<a href="message.php">see</a> | '.
             '<a href="delete.php?msg_id='.$row['msg_id'].'">delete</a>';

    ?>

</li>

<?php
/* Output:
       * message(id: message_id) | sent at row_data see | delete.


// [link]see[/link to message.php] | [link]delete[/link to delete.php]

*/?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I found the problem, i've forgot an "echo".
I wanted to do delete.php?myvariable=12040